# Allowing null String in DateTime.parse()

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

I am trying to format a String containing a date into a different Date format. I get the data from a Firestore document. When I pull the data into my UI of my flutter app I want to convert it to DateTime type so I can format it differently.
**EDIT** I added the suggested edit.

```
if (trxnProvider.sellerDisclosure24a != null && trxnProvider.sellerDisclosure24a != "") {
                final String? sellerDisclosure24a = trxnProvider.sellerDisclosure24a;
                _dt = DateTime.parse(sellerDisclosure24a);
                sellerDisclosure24aController.text = DateFormat('EE,  MM-dd-yyyy').format(_dt) ?? "";
              } else {
                sellerDisclosure24aController.text = "";
              }
```

However, I am getting the following error at this line

```
_dt = DateTime.parse(trxnProvider.sellerDisclosure24a);
```

The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. (Documentation)
'sellerDisclosure24a' refers to a property so it couldn't be promoted. See http://dart.dev/go/non-promo-property (trxn_provider.dart:55).

I have tried adding both "?" and "!" but I still get the error. How do I deal with this null safety issue? As you can see I am checking that data exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a local copy of `trxnProvider.sellerDisclosure24a` and use it instead:

```dart
// A local copy!
final String? sellerDisclosure24a = trxnProvider.sellerDisclosure24a;

if (sellerDisclosure24a != null && sellerDisclosure24a != "") {
  _dt = DateTime.parse(sellerDisclosure24a);
  sellerDisclosure24aController.text = DateFormat('EE,  MM-dd-yyyy').format(_dt) ?? "";
} else {
  sellerDisclosure24aController.text = "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68595530/edit) with your updated code?

Comment: @LostTexan You must add the `final String? sellerDisclosure24a` **outside** the if statement, not inside. Also, you're still using `trxnProvider.sellerDisclosure24a` inside the if condition when you should use `sellerDisclosure24a`. Read my answer carefully.